# Como instalar o Grunt offline?

Tags: node.js, npm, grunt

Já tenho o `Node.js` e `Npm` instalados e queria saber se existe uma forma de instalar o Grunt e utilizá-lo offline?

Answer (score 3):

Para instalar o `Grunt`, assim qualquer outra dependência `npm` você precisa estar conectado à internet.

Depois de instalado o `Grunt` só vai precisar de internet se alguma `task` descrita por você precisar desta conexão. Em vias de regra ele não precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi respondido pelo [@FReNeTiC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116492/41113), você **precisa de internet** para instalar o `Grunt` pelo `npm`.

Isso, ou você pode pegar um pen drive, encontrar um amigo seu que já possui o `Grunt` instalado, conectar o pen drive no pc do seu amigo e copiar o código-fonte dele. Feito isso você pode "instalar" o `Grunt` no seu computador apenas colando o código-fonte do pen drive para dentro do seu sistema. **Simples assim!**